# html nested tables agility pack valid xpath

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Assuming nested tables don't have unique attributes ( id , class or anything else )  to get the required one via

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@width='500']")
```

Does XPath prohibit using table several times in its path ?

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/center/table"))
```

throws exception as SelectNodes returns null.

If so how to tackle parsing of html with nested tables without specific attributes  with Agility Pack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just missed "td" tag in my path. So

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td/center/table/tr/td/center/table"))
```

does work. That actually answers my question. 
Other workaround to get the same table assuming there are unique attribute values in parent elements could be

```
HtmlNode tbl = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@height='643']/center/table");
```